# Android: Adobe air crashes on launch when ANE used (EasyPush)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, debugging, actionscript, air

I am trying to implement the MilkmanGames EasyPush ANE for Android.

https://www.milkmanplugins.com/as3doc/easypush/com/milkmangames/nativeextensions/EasyPush.html

When either of these functions is called the apk crashes:

```
EasyPush.oneSignal.registerForNotifications();
EasyPush.initOneSignal(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID, GCM_PROJECT_NUMBER, true);
```

The error given is 'Unfortunately, XXX has stopped'.

The console output in Flash Builder reports nothing once either function is called.

How can I see a more detailed log of whats happening?

I am sure the ANE initiates correctly because the other functions of the ANE work. The exact same code also works on iOS.

I am using Air 26, I have tried an older version of air. I have tried different devices running Android 5/6, I have tried initiating the ANE at the very start of the program and later on.

The closest issue I found was here https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2189025 however no definitive resolution was stated.

Answer (score 0):

The following permissions must be set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```